# IE8 div overflow not visible (cut off) due to opacity filter

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I use jQuery and fade in `div`s.  Works great on all browsers, but IE8 (I suspect other IE versions as well) will cut off `div`s that overflow an outer `div` when their opacity is set with `filter: alpha(opacity=100)`.  If you copy and paste the following into a file and load that with IE8, you'll see the blue square gets cut off because it overflows its outer `div`.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.outer {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    background-color: #700;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #00f;
    background-color: #007;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I get this to work where the inner div is allowed to overflow (yes I've tried `overflow: visible`) and I can use jQuery's animation mechanism for opacity?

Comment: I just tried your code with IE8 and it does overflow... It is probably due to your jquery code, can you check it please?

Comment: I copied and pasted that code from an .html file loaded in IE8...  do you have compatibility mode on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your example it's the Doctype or lack thereof causing it to break in IE8, but overall it's a problem with IE filters and hasLayout even with a proper Doctype is still happens in IE7.  While not sure what exactly you're trying to animate I've come up with a workaround for the example in your OP

The key is not to have the `outer` div positioned, if you need it to be, wrap it another div which "place-holds" the position. The other thing I found was that IE could also do with an opacity filter on the `inner` div, but you may not in your real code

here's some workaround code:

**CSS**

```
#wrap{ position: absolute; top: 30px; left:150px}

.outer {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    background-color: #700;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);  
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #00f;
    background-color: #007;
}

button {position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 100px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Toggle Fade</button>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('button').click(function(e) {
        $('.outer, .inner').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    }); 

});
```

If the toggle is not also applied to the inner div, then the animation is rather jerky in IE, it smoothly fades the outer div but the inner div just shows/hides instantly

the other browsers don't need opacity on `inner` as they rightly inherit it.. so on that one it's up to you wether you need that filter on `inner`

Comment: Interesting that you mentioned my issue with IE8 is the lack of DOCTYPE declaration.  In my website where this is a real issue I do have a DOCTYPE.  Through trial and error, I narrowed down the problem to the above code.  But it turns out you're right, adding a DOCTYPE does fix this in my test html.  So I guess I need to narrow down the real problem some more.  I don't really care about IE7 for this.

Comment: your solution does in fact work correctly for me.  I do have some opacity smoothness issues like you mentioned, but it's with the background of outer..  anyway, at least it looks good before and after animation.  thanks.